# MySQL Crash dump on AlmaLinux 8

Tags: mysql-8.0

I have sent SIGABRT to MySQL process but I am not getting the crash dump file. Server is AlmaLinux 8.8 (4.18.0-477.21.1.el8_8.x86_64 x86_64 x86_64) and MySQL version is 8.0.32.

Set the configuration as follows and restarted to no avail:

```
[mysqld]
core-file

[mysqld_safe]
core-file-size=unlimited
```

Set the core to unlimited

```
$  cat /proc/`pidof -s mysqld`/limits|egrep '(Limit|core)'
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max core file size        unlimited            unlimited            bytes
```

I tried setting these values as below but it is not accepted and result in MySQL failing to boot up.

```
[mysqld]
core-file
core-file-size=unlimited
core-file-path=/home/crash/apps/
```

I tried setting the core dumps in systemd and restarted MySQL. Issue is still there.

```
LimitCORE=infinity
```

It works with gcore but I want to test it when I send SIGABRT to MySQL. MySQL failed last time with SIGABRT and I want to test dump is working as expected.

When looking at the crash dump, it says it's writing the core file but there is nothing found

```
2023-11-26T21:54:46Z UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
BuildID[sha1]=40c1f0e0d826a573f7f320e98f4b61484baf534a
Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x100000
/usr/libexec/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x41) [0x5649f366bc51]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(print_fatal_signal(int)+0x3c3) [0x5649f26b1f43]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x6d) [0x5649f26b1fbd]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x12cf0) [0x7f19d4f15cf0]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__poll+0x51) [0x7f19d006b251]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(Mysqld_socket_listener::listen_for_connection_event()+0x68) [0x5649f26a7918]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(mysqld_main(int, char**)+0x38e9) [0x5649f2443d39]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe5) [0x7f19cff81d85]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_start+0x2e) [0x5649f242334e]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
Writing a core file
```